# How to interpret H2O's confusion matrix?

Tags: r, h2o, confusion-matrix

I am using h2o version 3.10.4.8.

```
library(magrittr)
library(h2o)

h2o.init(nthreads = -1, max_mem_size = "6g")

data.url <- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DarrenCook/h2o/bk/datasets/"

iris.hex <- paste0(data.url, "iris_wheader.csv") %>%
  h2o.importFile(destination_frame = "iris.hex")

y <- "class"
x <- setdiff(names(iris.hex), y)


model.glm <- h2o.glm(x, y, iris.hex, family = "multinomial")

preds <- h2o.predict(model.glm, iris.hex)

h2o.confusionMatrix(model.glm)
h2o.table(preds["predict"])
```

This is the output of `h2o.confusionMatrix(model.glm)`:

```
Confusion Matrix: vertical: actual; across: predicted
                Iris-setosa Iris-versicolor Iris-virginica  Error      Rate
Iris-setosa              50               0              0 0.0000 =  0 / 50
Iris-versicolor           0              48              2 0.0400 =  2 / 50
Iris-virginica            0               1             49 0.0200 =  1 / 50
Totals                   50              49             51 0.0200 = 3 / 150
```

Since it says across:predicted, I interpret this to mean that the model made 50 (0 + 48 + 2) predictions that are Iris-versicolor.

This is the output of `h2o.table(preds["predict"])`:

```
          predict Count
1     Iris-setosa    50
2 Iris-versicolor    49
3  Iris-virginica    51
```

This tells me that the model made 49 predictions that are Iris-versicolor.

Is the confusion matrix incorrectly labelled or did I make a mistake in interpreting the results?

Comment: it's the other way : actual labels are vertical (row names) and predicted labels are across (columns names). It's a bit confusing, but look at error rate, it has no sense in the other way around

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not make a mistake; the labels are confusing (and causing people to think that the rows and columns were switched).  This was [fixed recently](https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-4250) and will be included in the next release of H2O.

Answer (score 3):

Row names (vertical) are the actual labels.

Column names (across) are the predicted labels.